# Accessing GPS data on Sony AS30V with Remote API

Tags: camera, sony

is it possible to access the live GPS data from a Sony Action Cam AS30V using the remote API? 
Just Lat/Lon would do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible at this time.  However you can always access the GPS data from the phone/tablet that the Action Cam is connected to.